# remember user checked boxes populated from db

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form with several check boxes populated from a db

***CODE:***

```
// populating Checkboxes from db
    echo '<div>
        <label for="'.$n['eName'].'">'.$n['eName'].'</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="skills[]" id="'.$n['eName'].'" value="'.$n['id'].'" '.(isset($_POST[$n['eName']]) ? 'checked="checked"' : '') .' />
    </div>';
```

The problem is when the user select some of these check-boxes and submit the form and get error, the form can not remember his choices and he has to re-select them again.

what can I do to go over this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not correct:

```
isset($_POST[$n['eName']]
```

You should look in the $_POST['skills'] array.

According to your implementation of *$n['eName']* the following code might work:

```
echo '<div>
    <label for="'.$n['eName'].'">'.$n['eName'].'</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="skills['.$n['eName'].']" id="'.$n['eName'].'" value="'.$n['id'].'" '.(isset($_POST['skills'][$n['eName']]) ? 'checked="checked"' : '') .' />
</div>';
```

ps: Be warned that any quotation in *$n['eName']* would most likely break your code - one should take measures for these cases.

**Edit:**

```
<form method=post>
<?php

$n['id']='someid';
$n['eName'] = 'test';

echo '<div>
    <label for="'.$n['eName'].'">'.$n['eName'].'</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="skills['.$n['eName'].']" id="'.$n['eName'].'" value="'.$n['id'].'" '.(isset($_POST['skills'][$n['eName']]) ? 'checked="checked"' : '') .' />
</div>';
?>
<input type=submit >
</form>
```

Comment: I've made up a simple page for you to illustrate that in fact it is working. I'll add the code above.

Comment: my mistake, sorry I didn't update the `name="skills['.$n['eName'].']"` in my test.. sorry for that... it's working and accepted as an answer